# css `text-align` on input elements in `<fieldset>`

Tags: html, css

I produced the following code in HTML and CSS

```css
  * {
   font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
   color: #665544;
  }
  input {
   border-bottom: 1px dotted #dcdcdc;
   border-top: none;
   border-right: none;
   border-left: none;
   padding: 5px;
   width: 280px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  input:focus {
   border: 1px dotted #dcdcdc;
   outline: none;
  }
  input#submit {
   color: #ffffff;
   background-color: #665544;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 5px;
   width: 80px;
  }
  input#submit:hover {
   color:#665544;
   background-color: #efefef;
  }
  fieldset {
   width: 350px;
   border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
   border-radius: 10px;
   padding: 10px 20px;
   text-align: right;
  }
  legend {
   background-color: #efefef;
   border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
   border-radius: 10px;
   padding: 10px 20px;
   text-align: left;
   text-transform: uppercase;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Styling Fieldsets and Legends</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Newsletter</legend>
   <label for="name">Name: </label><input type="text" id="name" />
   <label for="email">Email: </label><input type="text" id="email" />
   <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" id="submit" />
  </fieldset>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now what I'm confused about is the text-align property.

I thought the `text-align` property only applies to text within a given element.

When I set `text-align:right;` in `fieldset` I expect all the text in the form to move to the right in the page.

So why does the `input` element then also move to the right even though the property involves text?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly.

The `text-align` property describes how inline content is aligned in its parent block element.

Text is an example of inline content, but this also apply to other inline elements as well.

Comment: but if that's the case with `text-align` then can't I just use `align` instead?

Comment: If there was an `align` css property you might be able to use it, but there isn't one :)

Comment: so you can use text align to say move all elements inside a div to the right if the css code says `div {text-align:right}`?

Comment: As mentioned - the `text-align` is relevant for inline content.

Answer (score 1):

The `text-align` property will affect all all textual content of a block-level element, as well as `display: inline` and `display: inline-block` elements.  Your `<input>` element is an inline element by default, and so it is affected by the parent fieldset's `text-align` property.

See this article: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-align/

It may also be helpful to note that elements defaulted to `display: inline` are defaulted this way because the CSS designers expected them to be intermingled in line with the text.   Therefore, it would not make sense if they were not also aligned like the text.

Answer (score 1):

input elements are inline elements, so they are affected by the text-align CSS property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements

If you are only trying to align the label elements, you could specify fieldset label { } in your CSS.